# how to retrieve password in django

Tags: django

How do we retrieve a password of an user?

```
u = User.objects.get(username__exact=username)
print u.password
```

displays `sha1$f0971$441cac8f604d49869e33ca125a76253a02fef64e`

Is there a function to find the password from this encoded string?

Comment: i need to email the password, when the user clicks on forgot password link. but since it's impossible what is the workaround?

Comment: Use the built-in functionality to reset the password - ie create a new one rather than emailing the original.

Comment: i have seen many websites providing this feature. Sad, django doesn't provide a workaround

Comment: No, it's not sad. It's **good**. If it's possible to access the password, it's possible for hackers to get it. Storing hashes makes that impossible. Websites that don't do this are insecure and you shouldn't trust them with your data.

Comment: Im using ldap for user authentication in django 2.0, and i need to create an endpoint to authenticate user from another application just passing the username to then redirect them. Isnt yet something to retrieve the raw password?

Comment: You should never email a password in plain text. Ever. If you can do this then your site has serious security flaws, and I for one would not use it! Email a link to reset the password instead, or change the password yourself, set the new one to expired so it needs changing when they log in, and mail them that instead. These are both acceptable methods, though the first is to be preferred.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

No. It's impossible, by design. But there should never be a need to do it anyway.

Answer (score 17):

Due to security restrictions the password hash method is one way. You will need to reset that users password.

Try using the `set_password(raw_password)` method to give the user a new password. Remember to call the `save()` method to ensure you save the change to the database.

```
u = User.objects.get(username__exact=username)
u.set_password(raw_password)
u.save()
```

Answer (score 8):

You can check if the password is correct with:

`u.check_password("your password")`

This method and `u.set_password("you password")` solves all of your problems.

`sha1$f0971$441cac8f604d49869e33ca125a76253a02fef64e` is:

hash function algorithm `$` salt `$` hash code

Answer (score 6):

no. and there shouldn't be. as part of the security, passwords are passed through a one-way function before they are saved, so that they aren't reveled if the database is compromised

what you can do is *replace* the user's password with one you know. this is how (good) site's "forgot your password" functions work: they send you a new random password, not your old one, since they (shouldn't) have access to it

Answer (score 4):

No, the field contains the salted hash of the password. from the string we know it's SHA1 function. If you have the password, you will be able to produce the same hash value which acts as the footprint. For security reason there should be now way to recover the password in a economical means (you can still brute force, but will take long time).,

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can get the existing password because that password is been converted to salt hash.