# Django POST Request: getting data

Tags: python, django, rest, curl

I'm building a REST API with django, and using this curl command to send a POST request to one of my functions:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @/Users/name/desktop/test.json http://127.0.0.1:8000 -u username
```

The localhost address takes in the POST request, process the json file provided with the -d flag and then returns a JSONResponse. I was wondering how, in my django function, I would get the username entered into this request?

Let's say my function is named and has the parameter as follows:

```
def train(request):
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to retrieve password in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10622199/how-to-retrieve-password-in-django)

Comment: modified the question to just obtain the username. but it still doesn't. maybe i'm just confused but i can't figure out how to get the username after the -u flag?

Answer (score 0):

Django `request` object contains [the `user`](http://.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.user) attribute.

> From the AuthenticationMiddleware: An instance of AUTH_USER_MODEL representing the currently logged-in user.

Comment: why does this return anonymous user? also - the link doesn't work. all I need is the username to then lookup in my firebase databse i'm creating

Comment: What do you do to authenticate users? Have you implemented anything?

Comment: was planning to just check to see if they're already in my set of users in my firebase table (by username). is this wrong? It's pretty early so I haven't implemented anything yet.

Comment: I believe you haven't created any users. If it is true then an anonymous user is expected because no user is logged-in.

Comment: should i just use this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/ to create and authenticate users? how would i go about it? thank you so much for this help btw!

Comment: Yes, this doc is what you need to understand Django auth.

Comment: last question: in the curl command how would I provide the username, password so that i can access it with request.POST['username']. I currently have -u username:password but that doesn't work.